# Raspberry Pi CUPS printing canon MG5660 not actually printing

Tags: raspbian, printing, cups

I have an up to date raspberry Pi connected over wifi, and a Canon MG5660 connected over wifi.

I have installed CUPS on the Pi. 
The web interface for CUPS detected the network printer and went all the way through the wizard, (picking the Canon MG5600 series printer driver assuming it would cover the 5660) all successful, no errors.

But when I print anything, no job seems to make it to the printer. The job que of CUPS says the jobs have been completed, and gives a completetion time, but nothing ever prints out.

I have tested the printer with my Windows machine just fine.

When restarting CUPS i get the following in /var/log/cups/error_log:

```
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon_MG5600_series-Gray..' already exists
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateProfile: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Canon_MG5600_series-RGB..' already exists
W [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] failed to CreateDevice: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Canon_MG5600_series' already exists
E [10/Jan/2016:14:33:01 +1100] Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.
E [10/Jan/2016:14:34:05 +1100] [cups-deviced] PID 2866 (snmp) stopped with status 1!
E [10/Jan/2016:14:41:30 +1100] Unable to open listen socket for address [v1.::]:631 - Address family not supported by protocol.
```

I don't think the ColorManger errors are really important, and that the Port 631 is realted to the CUPS webgui

Answer (score 2):

**Address family not supported by protocol** seems to be a fairly common error with CUPS. If [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=660969#p660969) is to be believed, go to the CUPS printer administration page — http://localhost:631/ — and click "Resume Printer".

Comment: I couldn't find the "resume printer" button, so I went to the maintenance drop down, paused the printer, and then resumed it.


Tried a test page from leafpad, no go. It said print "completed"


Canon_MG5600_series (Idle, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared)
Description: Canon MG5600 series
Location: Study
Driver: Canon PIXMA MG5300 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: dnssd://Canon%20MG5600%20series._printer._tcp.local/
Defaults: job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided